# Failed to build "polari" a gnome apps using gnome builder

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, gnome-builder

I am a newcomer to gnome app building. I am trying to build polari app using gnome builder on Ubuntu 18.04. I am getting the following error

> meson /home/yuvraj/Projects/polari . --prefix /app
> The Meson build system
> Version: 0.45.1
> Source dir: /home/yuvraj/Projects/polari
> Build dir: /home/yuvraj/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/Polari/builds/default-host-master
> Build type: native build
> Project name: polari
> Native C compiler: cc (gcc 7.3.0 "cc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0")
> Build machine cpu family: x86_64
> Build machine cpu: x86_64
> Program gjs found: YES (/usr/bin/gjs)
> Program js60 found: NO
> Program desktop-file-validate found: YES (/usr/bin/desktop-file-validate)
> Program appstream-util found: YES (/usr/bin/appstream-util)
> Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
> Native dependency gio-2.0 found: YES 2.56.3
> Native dependency gtk+-3.0 found: YES 3.22.30
> Native dependency telepathy-glib found: YES 0.24.1
> Native dependency gobject-introspection-1.0 found: YES 1.56.1
> Native dependency gjs-1.0 found: NO found '1.52.5' but need: '>= 1.53.90'
>
> meson.build:40:0: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'gjs-1.0' ['>= 1.53.90'] found '1.52.5'.

I did try installing all the build dependencies, but still no help.
The build profile is default
and Runtime is host operating system

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution accidentally. First of all internet connection must be good. Second the build profile must be that of the project not the default one. Third runtime must be org.gnome.Sdk, here the builder may crash sometimes but eventually will work.